# Why the results from R don't match Spark MLlib?

Tags: r, scala, apache-spark, linear-regression

I have a simple csv file (99 observation, the file is attached) and I want to do a simple regression and predict a field on my file (Energy consumption "y_3"). I applied Linear regression (*lm method in caret*, code is at the end) in R and *LinearRegressionWithSGD* (code at the end) in MLlib, Spark.

**But the RMSE in Spark is 20 times more than R.**

So I am confused with these results and any help would be appriciated
Thanks

CSV:

```
y_3,x_6,x_7,x_73_1,x_73_2,x_73_3,x_8
2995.3846153846152,17.0,1800.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,12.0
2236.304347826087,17.0,1432.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,12.0
2001.9512195121952,35.0,1432.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,5.0
992.4324324324324,17.0,1430.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,12.0
4386.666666666667,26.0,1430.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,25.0
1335.9036144578313,17.0,1432.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,5.0
1097.560975609756,17.0,1100.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,5.0
3526.6666666666665,26.0,1432.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,12.0
506.8421052631579,17.0,1430.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,5.0
2095.890410958904,35.0,1430.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,12.0
720.0,35.0,1430.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,5.0
2416.5,17.0,1432.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,12.0
3306.6666666666665,35.0,1800.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,12.0
6105.974025974026,35.0,1800.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,25.0
1400.4624277456646,35.0,1800.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,5.0
1414.5454545454545,26.0,1430.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,12.0
5204.68085106383,26.0,1800.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,25.0
1812.2222222222222,17.0,1800.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,12.0
2763.5928143712576,35.0,1100.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,12.0
1192.5991189427314,26.0,1800.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,5.0
5332.075471698113,26.0,1432.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,25.0
3318.157894736842,17.0,1100.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,25.0
1551.063829787234,35.0,1432.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,5.0
7998.75,35.0,1800.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,25.0
1800.0,26.0,1800.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,5.0
1829.0683229813665,17.0,1100.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,12.0
3396.0,35.0,1432.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,12.0
1911.6666666666667,26.0,1100.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,12.0
2160.0,26.0,1430.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,12.0
1777.5,17.0,1430.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,12.0
2089.756097560976,35.0,1800.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,5.0
740.8092485549133,17.0,1100.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,5.0
617.4683544303797,17.0,1100.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,5.0
3787.714285714286,17.0,1800.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,25.0
2450.958904109589,26.0,1800.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,12.0
531.0891089108911,26.0,1430.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,5.0
1108.1739130434783,26.0,1100.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,5.0
6538.378378378378,26.0,1432.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,25.0
6641.0526315789475,26.0,1800.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,25.0
2367.169811320755,26.0,1100.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,12.0
3708.2517482517483,17.0,1100.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,25.0
3253.090909090909,26.0,1100.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,12.0
1824.5454545454545,35.0,1432.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,5.0
2153.1645569620255,17.0,1800.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,12.0
3633.3333333333335,26.0,1800.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,12.0
4645.714285714285,17.0,1100.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,25.0
1575.5294117647059,35.0,1800.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,5.0
1146.6666666666667,17.0,1800.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,5.0
3042.3529411764707,26.0,1432.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,12.0
3841.2,26.0,1430.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,25.0
7625.060240963855,35.0,1432.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,25.0
1120.9580838323354,17.0,1432.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,5.0
936.8421052631579,35.0,1100.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,5.0
2637.0,35.0,1430.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,12.0
3738.4615384615386,35.0,1432.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,12.0
7002.580645161291,35.0,1432.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,25.0
2853.6585365853657,35.0,1100.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,12.0
2553.846153846154,26.0,1432.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,12.0
1153.2558139534883,17.0,1800.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,5.0
3793.170731707317,35.0,1800.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,12.0
1106.1818181818182,26.0,1100.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,5.0
1703.5714285714287,26.0,1432.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,5.0
1269.4736842105262,26.0,1800.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,5.0
2422.0408163265306,17.0,1430.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,25.0
1301.860465116279,35.0,1100.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,5.0
6849.0,26.0,1100.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,25.0
3285.0,17.0,1430.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,25.0
4550.163934426229,17.0,1432.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,25.0
4993.548387096775,17.0,1432.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,25.0
6264.0,35.0,1800.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,25.0
1016.0,17.0,1432.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,5.0
5387.586206896552,17.0,1800.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,25.0
720.0,17.0,1430.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,5.0
7941.818181818182,35.0,1432.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,25.0
4184.1509433962265,17.0,1432.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,25.0
3758.048780487805,35.0,1432.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,12.0
6425.454545454545,35.0,1100.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,25.0
1071.36,26.0,1432.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,5.0
974.7692307692307,17.0,1800.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,5.0
2659.8058252427186,26.0,1800.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,12.0
5697.0,35.0,1430.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,25.0
4967.027027027027,35.0,1430.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,25.0
5734.285714285715,35.0,1100.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,25.0
1529.1640866873065,17.0,1100.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,12.0
2667.6923076923076,17.0,1432.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,12.0
2655.5844155844156,17.0,1100.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,12.0
831.0132158590309,26.0,1100.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,5.0
3635.121951219512,35.0,1100.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,12.0
1080.0,35.0,1430.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,5.0
4947.096774193548,26.0,1100.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,25.0
968.7272727272727,26.0,1430.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,5.0
1626.0,26.0,1432.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,5.0
2788.3229813664598,35.0,1800.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,12.0
1800.0,35.0,1100.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,5.0
5796.923076923077,26.0,1432.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,25.0
5105.142857142857,26.0,1800.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,25.0
4594.782608695652,26.0,1100.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,25.0
3519.4736842105262,17.0,1800.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,25.0
```

R code:

```
library(caret)
library(fscaret)
set.seed(123)
data.main <- read.csv(file="data_2.csv",head=TRUE,sep=",")
split <- createDataPartition(y = data.main$y_3, p = 0.8, list = FALSE)
train <- data.main[split,]
test <- data.main[-split,]
lmCVFit.lm <-train(y_3 ~ ., 
                 data = train, 
                 method = "lm")
p <- predict.train(lmCVFit.lm, test[,-1])
t <- test$y_3
n <- nrow(test)
mse.lm <- MSE(p, t, n)
rmse.lm <- RMSE(p, t, n)
```

Spark code:

```
val datadir = new String("data directory");
val headerAndRows = sc.textFile(datadir + "/data_2.csv");
val header = headerAndRows.first;
val data = headerAndRows.filter(_(0) != header(0));
val parsedData = data.map { line =>
    val parts = line.split(',')
    LabeledPoint(parts(0).toDouble, Vectors.dense(parts(1).split(' ').map(_.toDouble)))
    }.cache()
// Split data into training and test
val splits = parsedData.randomSplit(Array(0.8, 0.2), seed = 11L);
val train = splits(0).cache
val test = splits(1).cache
val algorithm = new LinearRegressionWithSGD()
    algorithm.setIntercept(true)
    algorithm.optimizer
    .setNumIterations(100)
    .setStepSize(0.5)
    .setUpdater(new SquaredL2Updater())
    .setRegParam(10.0)
val new_model = algorithm.run(train)
val valuesAndPreds = test.map { point =>
    val prediction = new_model.predict(point.features)
    val r = (point.label, prediction)
    r
    }
val residuals = valuesAndPreds.map {case (v, p) => math.pow((v - p), 2)}
val MSE = residuals.mean();
val RMSE = math.pow(MSE, 0.5);
```

Comment: What are the respective results?

Comment: I think, it depends on internal algorithms that used in both Spark and R

Comment: I don't think this matches your CSV file you posted: LabeledPoint(parts(0).toDouble, Vectors.dense(parts(1).split(' ').map(_.toDouble)))

Comment: @Pascal: I got RMSE~700 in R and RMSE~13000 in Spark

Comment: @pzecevic Yes, it matches without any error.

Comment: @kaushal Yes it should be depend on internal algorithms, but the results should be near and not too far from each other! what do you think?

Comment: @Pascal Yes your results from R match mine. The small variation is due to different seeds.

Comment: Yes, mine is also RMSE=545.8172 for seed=123

Comment: Yes, I said RMSE is around 700 because I already tested for different seeds and different training sizes (0.7, 0.75, 0.8) and the results varied around these numbers.

Comment: When you compare prediction in R and Spark, is there any difference?

Comment: No, I meant you are splitting the features with ' ', and it's a CSV

Comment: @pzecevic Yes, you are right. But the problem is still remained!

Comment: @Pascal Yes, the prediction values are higher in Spark compare to R. That's why the RMSE in Spark is 20 times of R.

Comment: So you have to check why prediction in Spark are higher.

Comment: Then I would suggest you increase the number of iterations and experiment with different step sizes